# Как добавить webapp-директорию в уже существующее приложение maven (IntelliJ IDEA)?

Tags: java, maven

Как можно добавить `webapp`-директорию (с особым значком) в проект `IntelliJ IDEA`, если это не было сделано путём выбора архетипа при создании проекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уточнение. Речь идёт о Web-модуле.

Comment: что вы хотите этим достичь?

Comment: Я хочу привести структуру приложения в соответствующий вид.

Comment: соответсвующий чему? у проекта в IDEA один вид, а у стандартного проекта maven другой (зависит от плагинов).

Comment: Соответствующий архетипу Web Application (добавил картинку в вопрос).

Comment: у вас уже есть директория **webapp** и файлы в ней?

Comment: нет, ничего нет. это скриншот из видео

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте так:

1. File -> Project Structure
2. Facets -> кнопка **+** -> Web
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Выбирает свой модуль -> кнопка OK
4. И настраиваете **Web Resources Directory** (обычно `<путь до вашего проекта>/src/main/webapp`) и **Deployment Descriptors** (обычно `<путь до вашего проекта>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`)
5. Нажимаете OK
6. Добавляет в **pom.xml** (если там этого еще нет)

   ```
   <!-- если packaging есть, то надо его заменить -->
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <!-- если dependency есть, то добавлять не нужно -->
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <!-- если plugin есть, то добавлять не нужно -->
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

Comment: Отлично! То, что нужно!